# Python/Selenium - How to webscrape this dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code runs fine and prints the title for all rows **but the rows with dropdowns**.

For example, row 4 has a dropdown if clicked. I implemented a *try* which would in theory initiate the dropdown, to then pull the titles.

But my click/scrape for the rows with these drop downs are not printing.

Expected output- Print all titles including the ones in dropdown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')

productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='card item-container session')
for property in productlist:
    sessiontitle=property.find('h4',class_='session-title card-title').text
    print(sessiontitle)
    try:
        ifDropdown=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-expand-action expand')
        ifDropdown.click()
        time.sleep(4)
        newTitle=driver.find_element_by_class_name('card-title').text
        print(newTitle)
    except:
        newTitle='none'
```

Comment: item-expand-action expand should be item-expand-action.expand

Comment: and your find, once adapted as in prior comment returns a list of 8 items to open

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues. First, when you locate from the driver by class and there is more than one, you need to separate them by dots, not spaces, so that the driver knows it's dealing with another class.
Second, find_elements returns a list, and the list has no .click(), so you get an error, which your except catches but assumes means there was no link to click.
I rewrote it (without soup for now) so that it instead checks (With the dot replacing space) for a link to open within the session and then loops over the new ones that appeared.
Here is what I have and tested. Note at the end this only gets the sessions and subsessions in the view. You will need to add logic to scroll and get the rest.

```
# stuff to initialize driver is above here, I used firefox
# Open the website page
URL = "https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list"
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(4)#time for page to populate


product_list=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.card.item-container.session')
#above line gets all top level sessions
for product in product_list:
    session_title=product.find_element_by_css_selector('h4.card-title').text
    print(session_title)
    dropdowns=product.find_elements_by_class_name('item-expand-action.expand')
    #above line finds dropdown within this session, if any
    if len(dropdowns)==0:#nothing more for this session
        continue#move to next session
    #still here, click on the dropdown, using execute because link can overlap chevron
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();",
                          dropdowns[0])
    time.sleep(4)#wait for subsessions to appear
    session_titles=product.find_elements_by_css_selector('h4.card-title')
    session_index = 0#suppress reprinting title of master session
    for session_title in session_titles:
        if session_index > 0:
            print("    " + session_title.text)#indent for clarity
        session_index = session_index + 1
    #still to do, deal with other sessions that only get paged into view when you scroll
    #that is a different question
```