# Selenium/BeautifulSoup - WebScrape this field

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

My code runs fine and prints the title for all rows but the rows with dropdowns.

For example, row 4 has a dropdown if clicked. I implemented a 'try' which would in theory click the dropdown, to then pull the titles.

But when i execute click() and try to print, for the rows with these drop downs, they are not printing.

Expected output- Print all titles including the ones in dropdown.

**A user has submitted an answer on this link [StackOverFlowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473642/selenium-webscrape-this-field#68474005) but the format of his answer was different and I do not know how to add fields such as date, time, chairs, or the field on the top which says "On demand" with his approach**

Any approach would be appreciated, would like to put into a dataframe. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')

new_titles = set()

productlist=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card item-container session']")
for property in productlist:
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(property,0,0).perform()
    time.sleep(4.5)
    sessiontitle=property.find_element_by_xpath(".//h4[@class='session-title card-title']").text
    #print(sessiontitle)
    ifDropdown=property.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='item-expand-action expand']")
    if(ifDropdown):
        ifDropdown[0].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        open_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-title')
        for open_title in open_titles:
            title = open_title.text
            if(title not in new_titles):
                print(title)
                new_titles.add(title)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium/Webscrape this field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473642/selenium-webscrape-this-field)

Comment: Another Dupe by Same OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472330/python-selenium-how-to-webscrape-this-dropdown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477401/webscrape-this-field-beautifulsoup-requests-python-selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478983/webscrape-a-field-selenium-beautifulsoup

Comment: they are not dupe.. there are fields referenced in this post not included in the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-expand-action expand')` command. The `find_elements_by_class_name('item-expand-action expand')` locator is wrong. Those web elements have multiple class names. To locate these elements you can use css_selector or XPath.
Also since there are several elements with dropdowns, to perform clicks on them you should iterate over them. You can not perform `.click()` on a list of web elements.
So your code should be like this:

```py
ifDropdown=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.item-expand-action.expand')
for drop_down in ifDropdown:
    drop_down.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Alternatively to the css_selector above you can use XPath as well:

```
ifDropdown=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="item-expand-action expand"]')
```

**UPD**
If you wish to print the added, new titles you can do this:

```py
ifDropdown=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.item-expand-action.expand')
for drop_down in ifDropdown:
    drop_down.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
newTitles=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-title')
for new_title in newTitles:
    print(new_title.text)
```

Here after expanding all the dropdown elements I'm getting all the new titles and then iterate over that list printing each element text.
`driver.find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list of web elements. You can not apply `.text` on a list, you have to iterate over list elements getting each single element text each time.
**UPD2**
The entire code opening dropdowns and printing their inner titles can be like this:
I'm doing this with Selenium, not mixing with bs4.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')

new_titles = set()

productlist=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card item-container session']")
for property in productlist:
    actions.move_to_element(property).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sessiontitle=property.find_element_by_xpath(".//h4[@class='session-title card-title']").text
    print(sessiontitle)
    ifDropdown=property.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='item-expand-action expand']")
    if(ifDropdown):
        ifDropdown[0].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        open_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-title')
        for open_title in open_titles:
            title = open_title.text
            if(title not in new_titles):
                print(title)
                new_titles.add(title)
```

Here I am checking if there is a dropdown. If do, I open it. Then getting all the currently existing opened titles. Per each such title I validate if it is new or was opened previously. If the title is new, not existing in the set I print it and add it to the set.

Comment: Click works well, but I cant seem to print any of the titles from the drop down?

Comment: Can you please possibly post the full code? I have made the update but still am printing the same result with the new update

Comment: Code does not print the drop downs accurately :/ If you check the outputs and the webpage, they do not match fully

Comment: Can you tell me what is not accurate with my answer? I can't debug this, this is why I'm asking you

Comment: Updated the `ifDropdown=property.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='item-expand-action expand']")` line

Comment: Also added scrolling for each property element in the loop for the case the next element is gone down because of expanding the dropdowns.  Please let me know if this fixed your problems or there are still any?

Comment: Hey thanks for response, I get an error saying : AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Removed `.build()` from there. Try again please

Comment: I think we are getting closer, but if you cross reference the output vs the page from webdriver, they still are not fully in sync.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What is not correct now?

Comment: While it is stored in new_titles, when i print new_titles, it does not seem to be in order.

This can be checked by doing a print on new_titles. Ideally id want the output saved in a dictionary/dataframe

Comment: Well, to put data in dictionary/df is definitely a new, additional question. Here on SO each question should be very specific. It's not about doing the entire project. So I'm sorry, but I feel I answered the initially asked question more than for 100%. You are welcome to accept this answer and ask a new question for putting the output to a dictionary/df.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to point out new_titles. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! What you are asking now is too difficult to do without python IDE and actual debugging the code...

Answer (score 0):

To get all the data, including the *date, time, chairs,* you can use only `requests`/`BeautifulSoup`. There's no need for `Selenium`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = []
url = "https://cslide.ctimeetingtech.com/esmo2021/attendee/confcal/session/list?p={}"

for page in range(1, 5):  # <-- Increase number of pages here
    with requests.Session() as session:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url.format(page)).content, "html.parser")
        for card in soup.select("div.card-block"):
            title = card.find(class_="session-title card-title").get_text()
            date = card.select_one(".internal_date div.property").get_text(strip=True)
            time = card.select_one(".internal_time div.property").get_text()
            try:
                chairs = card.select_one(".persons").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                chairs = "N/A"

            data.append({"title": title, "date": date, "time": time, "chairs": chairs})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output (truncated):

```
                                                                                                                                                                         title             date           time                                                                    chairs
0                                                                                                                                                Educational sessions on-demand  Thu, 16.09.2021  08:30 - 09:40                                                                       N/A
1                                                                                                                                                    Special Symposia on-demand  Thu, 16.09.2021  12:30 - 13:40                                                                       N/A
2                                                                                                                                          Multidisciplinary sessions on-demand  Thu, 16.09.2021  16:30 - 17:40                                                                       N/A
3                                                                                                                    MSD - Homologous Recombination Deficiency: BRCA and beyond  Fri, 17.09.2021  08:45 - 09:55                       Frederique Penault-Llorca(Clermont-Ferrand, France)
4                                                                                                          Servier - The clinical value of IDH inhibition in cholangiocarcinoma  Fri, 17.09.2021  08:45 - 10:15  Arndt Vogel(Hannover, Germany)Angela Lamarca(Manchester, United Kingdom)
5                                                                                                                   AstraZeneca - Redefining Breast Cancer – Biology to Therapy  Fri, 17.09.2021  08:45 - 10:15                                Ian Krop(Boston, United States of America)
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to capture all of the dropdowns. For example - if you go to the URL, look at line 4 of ur output. If you click this title (Illumina - Diagnosing Non-Small Cell Lung Cancer using Comprehensive Genomic Profiling) it does not capture all of the titles that drop down when this title is clicked

Comment: @VoidS There was a typo in my code. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hi, this still does not seem to capture the drop downs :(

Comment: Line 4 in the website has drop downs, those drop downs are not showing up in the output